# Changing Database Name In Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to change the database name in SQL SERVER 2008 and use it in another project. However it consist hundreds of stored procedures and the name of the database should be changed in the stored procedures as well. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The best solution was to back up the database and attach it as a new database. This way SQL Server automatically renamed the old database references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right mouse click a Database and choose Tasks->Generate Scripts.  Go through the Wizard and it will create a SQL script for you.  Make sure that you select all of the necessary options e.g. Create Database, Stored Procedures etc.  Once finished, you'll have a big script.  Find and replace the database name.

Comment: +1. When editing the script I would suggest that you remove the database name unless it is needed. Having the SPs of a DB knowing the DB name can give nasty effects if someone makes a copy of the db with another name for test purposes (the SPs of the test DB could update the live DB).

Comment: Just a clarification, because I'm a noob and I stared at this answer for a good ten minutes before realising what was going on. The "Generate Scripts" thing creates a big text file within the SQL editor. Find/Replace the database name on all the entries in that file, then click Execute. It will fail because the script tries to re-insert all of your existing stored procedures into the database. You will now have to delete all of the procedures you're updating, execute again, and they will be re-inserted, and it will look like nothing has happened. Now refresh the view and they will reappear.

Comment: Instructions given in a weird order because any set of instructions where the second line is "Now delete all of the stored procedures from your database" is stupid. My instructions at least result in an error message which tells you why you need to delete them :P

Comment: To solution was for creating the tables and SPs in different database where you aparently don't have any SP

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you export all your stored procedures as sql-files and then take a nice texteditor (like Notepad++) and make a file-search&replace-action to change all the names referenced inside the sql-files.

There is no other way around as far as I can say :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'd make next thing: I'd generate all scripts for database by Management Studio(`Right Click on DB -> Tasks -> Generate scripts`), after that I'd replace name of database (`Ctrl + H`).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the database, Tasks -> Generate scripts, select stored procedure, and open the scripts in sql editor.

Search and replace the database or string names.
replace Create procedure with Alter procedure.
Compile and done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this automatically.  You would have to manually change every stored procedure.

Do you really need to change the name?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to keep everything the same and use a different server or server instance? Are you going to have to maintain database changes through these two datbases with the different names?